# How to control an animation via touch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, rotateanimation

I'm creating an app that uses a disk to browse files and such, like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8051037/disk_ab1.png

I want to make it be able to spin as the user turns it, and I know I need to use a RotateAnimation, but I can't figure out how to make it follow the finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a custom view, see this examle which rotates a ball: [How can I use the animation framework inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893)

then you can use motion event to control the angle of rotation: [Android firing onTouch event for multiple ImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222688/android-firing-ontouch-event-for-multiple-imageviews/5223177#5223177)

Custom view can be transparent so you can combine it with other veiws in your layout.

Comment: Ok, i get the motion event thing, but I don't fully understand what I'm supposed to get out of the custom view sample.

Comment: Here is another example with a custom view, where a circle is drawn. All you need is to draw your own wheel and then animate it when finger touches the screen: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html Of course there are always different solutions, and you may come with your own, but it is good to understand how these examples work.