# How can I control the animation speed in android

Tags: android, animation

I have a music app and the music notations perform an animation from right to left, I want to control the animation speed, while they are performing.Can anyone please help me for that?

My animation layout is:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="500%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="10000" 
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

And my code to perform the animation is:

```
Animation am=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.note);
        music1.startAnimation(am);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380677/how-to-control-an-animation-via-touch

Answer (score 4):

set your android:duration with this help you can control your animation speed

```
android:duration="300"
```

Comment: Not like that, Is there any way to control the speed during the animations are permorming, by touch or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

change in the duration will control the speed of animation in your file.

```
  android:duration="10000" // here you have to change the time in milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement onTouchListener to control your animation speed at the run time. inside touch listener event put coding to change your animation duration.

Answer (score 0):

From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#java):

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.start()
```

In your case:

```
music.setDuration(setValue);
```